# Bootstrap 4 - Flex wrap after 5th item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve quite a specific layout using the newest Bootstrap 4. How it should work/look:
- first element/child should be a kind of 'hero', visible on 100% of container width
- all other items should be as thumbs
- the 'thumbs' row should include 4 items, next one should break/wrap to another row

So in theory new row should appear after 5th element (hero + 4 thumbs), but I have no clue how to approach that. My current code looks as follows:

HTML

```
<section id="videos">
  <div class="row gallery">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <dl class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap thumbs">
        <dt class="p-2 main-frame">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="p-2">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/111/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="p-2">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/354/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="p-2">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="p-2">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt> 
        <dt class="p-2">
          <a href="#" title="test it">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>
        </dt> 
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.thumbs dt:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}

.thumbs dt:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrf3np6g/)

What I'm doing wrong? Is it doable without additional js?

Comment: why not have the thumbs as `col-lg-3`

Comment: @Pete Because of the design ;)

Comment: that makes no sense, you want four thumbnails and the fifth to wrap so what has the design got to do with it unless the design doesn't match your description? https://jsfiddle.net/bzark54g/

Comment: maybe the description was incomplete/not precise enough. I want to achieve such effect: https://imgur.com/a/ujgTFpx

Comment: And the fiddle in my comment above doesn't achieve that?

Comment: i was struggling with that your solution was not responsive, meaning - I'm not sure whether there will be four or e.g. three items. But in fact I've approached the different topic and your reply, so I've used the class 'col' instead 'col-lg-3' and it works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `flex-wrap` is quite good.

But instead of `flex: 1;` which will enlarge your items to equal size, you can set a width of one fourth `width: calc(100% / 4);` to have four items in a row.

So you can leave your HTML and just change your CSS to

```css
.thumbs dt:not(:first-child) {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}

.thumbs dt:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caz8nvhL/1/)

Answer (score -1):

for every fourth img you can do:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  Hero goes here
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row img">
 <div class="col-3">
  img1
 </div>
 <div class="col-3">
  img2
 </div>
 <div class="col-3">
  img3
 </div>
 <div class="col-3">
    img4
 </div>
</div>
```

And then add same structure for the next 4 images.. if 4 images are to be shown per row.. The hero might not be desired to be added for each image row.

Some condition like

if(videoNr%4 == 0) // add image row with the next four

If you must use flex layout. This is a way to solve it, it will wrap to new line every fourth image without the need of any additional CSS:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img1</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img2</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img3</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img4</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img5</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img6</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img7</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img8</div>
  <div class="flex-fill w-25">img9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not answer his question. He wants a CSS (or alternatively JS) solution. Without changing the backend code. Atleast he did not mention the backend code.

Comment: In his question there is a html of the current markup, I assume that is possible to edit. Of course you need to write some code to itterate over all images. It could be written in JS or whatever. If the images are not hardcoded, if that the case it is just to paste the images in my markup, that will work. You might want som col-sm-6 or other variants for smaller screens!

Comment: Actually you don´t even need to add more img rows. Just add col-3 divs to this row, you can add 5 or 11.. or anything. They will wrap with four per row anyway. No need for extra css. Keep it simple.

Comment: Yeah that's true. It is possible! But i assume the author wants to have a flexbox solution since he asked for that and the post is tagged with it. But i get your point ofc! And i agree that this solution might be better in some cases. Still, that's not what the author asked for (atleast i guess).

Comment: You are right. If flex layout is a must I am out of topic :)